# Plot a scatter plot of sepal length versus sepal width of all the versicolor samples

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib . pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
% matplotlib inline
from sklearn . datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris ()
print (" Features : ", iris . feature_names )
print (" Labels : ", iris . target_names )

df = pd. DataFrame (np. column_stack ([ iris .data , iris.target ]), columns = iris . feature_names + [' lable '])
print(df)

x_feature = 0
y_feature = 1
x_column = iris.data[:, x_feature]
y_column = iris.data[:, y_feature]
plt.scatter(x_column, y_column, c=iris.target)
plt.xlabel(iris.feature_names[x_feature])
plt.ylabel(iris.feature_names[y_feature])
```

How do I plot a scatter plot of *sepal_length* versus *sepal_width* of all the
versicolor samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that all Versicolor samples are grouped together, you can change your code to:

```
x_column = iris.data[50:100, x_feature]
y_column = iris.data[50:100, y_feature]
plt.scatter(x_column, y_column)
```